# Why is make unavailable on the default Gentoo liveCD?

Tags: gentoo, make, livecd

Whilst attempting to install Gentoo on my desktop, I ran into some trouble getting my wireless card to work. [This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166038) is the card I am using. The modules included with the Live CD didn't detect my card, so I downloaded the drivers from the Rosewill website, and followed the build instructions.. up until it told me to use `make`.

The Gentoo Live CD doesn't come with `make`.

So, I am confused as to how I should continue from here.

**EDIT:** I ended up remembering I have a *really long* cat5 cable, and used that for the initial installation, and then compiled the drivers after chrooting into stage3

Comment: Because usually you would compile inside your stage3 chroot and not the livecd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's typical that Live CD's include developer tools such as `make` and  `autoconf`. Now I realize Gentoo is meant to be built from source but given your situation I think you're options are one of the following:

1. Compile the drivers on another Gentoo system that does have `make` and then manually copy the kernel .ko file(s) to the affected system.
2. Get the binary packages of `make`, `gcc`, etc. from `portage` on another Gentoo system and install them as packages into the Live CD system.
3. Try [SabayonLinux](http://www.sabayon.org/) instead of Gentoo.
4. Pick a different LiveCD distro that does work with your hardware and follow the Gentoo handbook using that distro instead of the Gentoo LiveCD.

Looking through the howto: [Installing Gentoo Using Packages on the liveDVD](http://dev.gentoo.org/~neddyseagoon/HOWTO_DVD11.xml) there are several mentions of a "sneakernet" installation method:

#### *excerpt*

> Second choice is a stage3 install supported by Sneakernet. This
>   differes only in that things are fetched from the internet using a
>   remote system or another operating system (or both) and loaded into
>   the growing install manually. Portage still builds everything. The use
>   of [sneakernet](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-3461249.html#3461249) is described elsewhere.

Given that I would think you're left to manually get the various bits you need using a secondary system, and manually load them into this system.

The details for setting up your network manually are here, in section 3 of the Gentoo handbook: [Configuring your Network](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/2004.3/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=3#doc_chap4).

Comment: Given that it is easy to chroot into a stage3, the LiveCD doesn't need these things.